# IndexError: image index out of range

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
def main():

    im = Image.open('terrain.png')
    ter = im.load()

    terr = []
    for row in range(500):
        trow = []
        for col in range(400):
            if ter[col,row][0:3] not in terrains:

                print((row,col))
                trow.append(5)
            else:
                trow.append(terrains[ter[col,row][0:3]])
        terr.append(trow)
    source = (200, 200)
    destination = (300, 300)
```

> File "/Users/pranushasoma/Downloads/hw1b.py", line 175, in main
>
> ```
> if ter[col,row][0:3] not in terrains:
> ```
>
> IndexError: image index out of range

What can I do about this error?

Comment: what is line 195 in your snippet ?

Comment: try printing just `ter[col,row]` (or check its length `(len(ter[col,row])` then adjust the slicing parameters `[0..n]` accordingly

Comment: Why do you hardcode the range for the rows and columns? You can extract these from your image object. And are you sure it shouldn't be `ter[row,col]`?